# Foreach with if repeating results

Tags: php, if-statement, foreach

I do an if for control the first row of my foreach but when i execute, the echo shows 3 times the same thing

```
    foreach ($fotoscards as $fotos) {
                $i == 1;
                if ($i == 1) {

                    echo "[{image:", $fotos , '},';
                    $i++;

                }
                else echo '{image:', $fotos , '},';
                    $i++;


            }
```

And the output i'm getting:

```
{image:pics/570212366814_1008100572561339_77379992_n3.jpg},
[{image:pics/570212366814_1008100572561339_77379992_n3.jpg},
 {image:},
 {image:pics/570212366814_1008100572561339_77379992_n3.jpg},
 {image:},
 {image:pics/655210502212_694548387334477_1457367303128125710_n.jpg},
 {image:pics/570212366814_1008100572561339_77379992_n3.jpg},
 {image:},
 {image:pics/655210502212_694548387334477_1457367303128125710_n.jpg},
 {image:pics/154212308582_908192572599216_6538482440643426144_n.jpg},
 {image:pics/570212366814_1008100572561339_77379992_n3.jpg},
 {image:},
 {image:pics/655210502212_694548387334477_1457367303128125710_n.jpg},
 {image:pics/154212308582_908192572599216_6538482440643426144_n.jpg},
 {image:},
 {image:pics/570212366814_1008100572561339_77379992_n3.jpg},
 {image:},
 {image:pics/655210502212_694548387334477_1457367303128125710_n.jpg},
 {image:pics/154212308582_908192572599216_6538482440643426144_n.jpg},
 {image:},
 {image:},
 {image:pics/570212366814_1008100572561339_77379992_n3.jpg},
 {image:},
 {image:pics/655210502212_694548387334477_1457367303128125710_n.jpg},
 {image:pics/154212308582_908192572599216_6538482440643426144_n.jpg},
 {image:},
 {image:},
 {image:pics/7593uphol1.jpg},
```

I want the output are:

```
[{image:pics/570212366814_1008100572561339_77379992_n3.jpg},
 {image:pics/655210502212_694548387334477_1457367303128125710_n.jpg},
 {image:pics/154212308582_908192572599216_6538482440643426144_n.jpg},
 {image:pics/7593uphol1.jpg},
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not setting your `$i` variable to 1 on line 2, you're comparing it to 1. Since I assume you haven't declared or set `$i` anywhere else, the else-statement is executed. So on line 2,

```
$i == 1;
```

should be

```
$i = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify the code by printing the initial bracket before the foreach loop:

```
        echo '[';
        foreach ($fotoscards as $fotos) {
            echo "{image:', $fotos , '},';
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you set the `$i` counter variable *inside* your `for` loop so it's value is set again to `1` at each iteration. You need to declare it once before the `for` loop.

Another problem is your `else` statements are not wrapped into brackets so your second `$i++` is executed even when the `if` passes. That's two times a `$i++` when you want only one.

```
$i = 1;
foreach ($fotoscards as $fotos) {
    if ($i == 1) {
        echo "[{image:", $fotos , '},';
        $i++;
    }
    else {
        echo '{image:', $fotos , '},';
        $i++;
    }
}
```

If you don't want an external counter you can use

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($fotoscards); $i++) {
    if ($i == 0) {
        echo "[{image:", $fotoscards[$i], '},';
        $i++;
    }
    else {
        echo '{image:', $fotoscards[$i], '},';
        $i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: I try all, but the output continues: [{image:pics/570212366814_1008100572561339_77379992_n3.jpg},[{image:pics/570212366814_1008100572561339_77379992_n3.jpg},[{image:pics/570212366814_1008100572561339_77379992_n3.jpg},{image:pics/655210502212_694548387334477_1457367303128125710_n.jpg},[{image:pics/570212366814_1008100572561339_77379992_n3.jpg},{image:pics/655210502212_694548387334477_1457367303128125710_n.jpg},[{image:pics/570212366814_1008100572561339_77379992_n3.jpg},{image:pics/655210502212_694548387334477_1457367303128125710_n.jpg},{image:},

Comment: Did you actually replace your code with mine ? Your error is obvious.

Comment: What's the content of `$fotoscards` ? Please update your question.